# TYPO3: How to create a localization for page content element in list view?

Tags: localization, typo3

I have non-used elements on my page. In list view I can see them. But now I want to create a page translation for this element. But in the list view there is no "Create new page translation" selection box. How can I create a localized element?

[This](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/339/listview.png/) is what I see? Where is the 2nd option?

Comment: Did you enabled 2nd option of the listview module? From my memory it should be possible.

Comment: I added a screenshot. The translation has already be done for "footer". But I don't know how to do this with my other element ... Where is the 2nd option?

Comment: My bad, maybe it's the extension that doesn't work properly. In tt-news for example you should see a translation button in listview.

Comment: But you can try the clipboard menu. Select #1, #2, #3 clipboard and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. If I select them I get "No elements".

Comment: There are some option in the default listview I'm missing in your screenshot like translation, select all, select item, etc. When you select the clipboard those option should appear.

Comment: What happens if you select a table in the listview? does it shows more options? You made a screenshot from the page but listview is for tables, too?

Comment: If I click "list only this table" I still don't see the options you mentioned. If I click on the plus at clipboard #1 I only get a search section below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In List module click the edit icon (pen symbol) of the content element. At the very top you will see a Language dropdown menu. Any language overlays that do not yet exist are marked with "[NEW]" (see Portuguese in the screenshot below). If you select one of those, the corresponding overlay record is immediately created and a you are presented with a form to fill in its content.

[image: Create new language overlay record]

Comment: I'm sure I tried that, but I never saw it. Now I tried with IE and yeah its there. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have a copy of the same project. In this copy the language selection box is not available. I don't know what I have done in the other project that it is displayed. Seems to be a bug in TYPO3?

Comment: Removing the answer flag is not motivating to help you any further. After all the answer is to the point of your question.
Are you sure you have created "Website language" records in the root of your page tree? See http://typo3.org/documentation/tips-tricks/multi-language-sites-in-typo3/ for details (look at section _2: The new "one-tree-fits-all-languages" concept_).

Comment: Sorry for the removing. The reason is that I thought it didn't was the solution to my problem. But in fact it is (on another element). My untranslated element was a page content object on an empty page. Because one time another language was already installed and removed one element had a translation another not. Now I wanted to create a translation for the untranslated element. But I had to create a translation (as you described) for the empty page which was the container for the element. Now I made this and I could create a translation for my page content object. Thanks!